# Get current URL before character "?"

Tags: php, url

I would like to know how can to get current url but before a `?` character:

```
http://www.example.com/pag1?q=ok
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
http://www.example.com/pag1
```

Comment: Regular expression or simple string functions using strpos to find ? and then take the first x characters with tuw strstr function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can explode your url as

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/pag1?q=ok';

$explodedURL= parse_url($url);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($explodedURL['host'].explodedURL['path']);

echo $explodedURL['scheme'].'://'.$explodedURL['host'].$explodedURL['path'];
```

Output:

```
Array
(
[scheme] => http
[host] => www.example.com
[path] => /pag1
[query] => q=ok
)
http://www.example.com/pag1
```

Comment: You should edit to include the library reference for the parse_url function because you can specify to retrieve only one component of the url, e.g. just the host or just the query

Comment: and if i don't know full url, to get it can use this code:  'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/pag1?q=ok’;
$pos = strpos($url, '?');
$yourstr = strstr($url, 0, $pos - 1);
```